# NestJS: "SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" when importing ttf font

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I'm creating a PDF document in a NestJS application. My problem is that I can't import the fonts.
They are correctly copied to the `/dist`-folder, but I'm getting the following error:

```
/dist/assets/Mulish-Italic.ttf:1

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at compileFunction (<anonymous>)
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
```

Import looks like this:

```
import MulishItalic from '../../assets/Mulish-Italic.ttf';
```

I have no idea on how to proceed here, appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're doing, you might find it easier and cleaner to use a node module for this font, such as [@fontsource/mulish](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fontsource/mulish).